# Assigning Struct members in C Using a Single Array?

Tags: arrays, c, windows, struct, syntax

I just came across this snippet of code in the book *Programming Windows*, and I really want to understand what is going on here. I thought I've seen all the different ways to declare a struct, but I have never seen it done like this before:

```
/*----------------------------------------
   BTNLOOK.C -- Button Look Program
                (c) Charles Petzold, 1998
  ----------------------------------------*/

#include <windows.h>

struct
{
     int     iStyle ;
     TCHAR * szText ;
}
button[] =
{
     BS_PUSHBUTTON,      TEXT ("PUSHBUTTON"),
     BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,   TEXT ("DEFPUSHBUTTON"),
     BS_CHECKBOX,        TEXT ("CHECKBOX"), 
     BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,    TEXT ("AUTOCHECKBOX"),
     BS_RADIOBUTTON,     TEXT ("RADIOBUTTON"),
     BS_3STATE,          TEXT ("3STATE"),
     BS_AUTO3STATE,      TEXT ("AUTO3STATE"),
     BS_GROUPBOX,        TEXT ("GROUPBOX"),
     BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, TEXT ("AUTORADIO"),
     BS_OWNERDRAW,       TEXT ("OWNERDRAW")
} ;
```

It is clear to me later in the code that this is essentially assigning the BS_*** constants to the int iStyle struct members, and assigning the strings to the TCHAR* szText members, and apparently naming the struct **button**.

As a novice C programmer, it looks like there is an array called **button** being declared with mismatched types (char* and int). Also, I usually see a **typedef** before struct when the name of the struct is after the first ending curly brace ( } ) like it is here.

I don't think there is anything Windows specific going on here, but I cannot find anything like this anywhere in any of my C textbooks or searching online, and I can't find the author explaining that part of his code in the book.

How does the compiler know to alternate between int and TCHAR in that "array" and assign the values correctly in the struct?

**EDIT:** Thanks to the users in the comments below, I see what is going on. I thought the array was somehow nested in the struct declaration, but I see now that the struct is the type of the array. To anyone who may stumble on this in the future, maybe this revision makes it clearer:

```
/*----------------------------------------
   BTNLOOK.C -- Button Look Program
                (c) Charles Petzold, 1998
  ----------------------------------------*/

#include <windows.h>

struct
{
     int     iStyle ;
     TCHAR * szText ;
}
button[] =
{
     { BS_PUSHBUTTON,      TEXT ("PUSHBUTTON")    },
     { BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,   TEXT ("DEFPUSHBUTTON") },
     { BS_CHECKBOX,        TEXT ("CHECKBOX")      }, 
     { BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,    TEXT ("AUTOCHECKBOX")  },
     { BS_RADIOBUTTON,     TEXT ("RADIOBUTTON")   },
     { BS_3STATE,          TEXT ("3STATE")        },
     { BS_AUTO3STATE,      TEXT ("AUTO3STATE")    },
     { BS_GROUPBOX,        TEXT ("GROUPBOX")      },
     { BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, TEXT ("AUTORADIO")     },
     { BS_OWNERDRAW,       TEXT ("OWNERDRAW")     }
} ;
```

Example Integer array:
**int** nums[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

Example Struct array:
**struct {...}** button[] = **{** *{ BS..., TEXT ("...") }*, *{ BS..., TEXT ("...") }*, ... **}**

Comment: It's an array of structures that lack tag. The initializer list is sloppily written, it would have been clearer if written as `{ BS_PUSHBUTTON,      TEXT ("PUSHBUTTON") },` - this initializes one struct item in the array.

Comment: "*...and apparently naming the struct button.*" Nope. "*...  it looks like there is an array called button*" Exactly

Comment: A decent compiler should generate a warning for that initializer. Like: "warning: missing braces around initializer". There should be a `{` before every int and a `}` after each string.

Comment: @Lundin
Thanks for the comments guys, I finally see it now, and thanks for the clarification on the braces. MSVC did not complain about the syntax but the additional braces would have made it much easier for me to understand.